# Process URL in the same way as Express does to get request parameters in a get command

Tags: node.js, express, routes, url-routing

I want to be able to get the parameters from a uri string in the **exact** same way as Express does. I can do it with regex or other string methods, but then I have a risk that it is not interpretted the same way as Express. I would prefer a way that even if Express has a bug and a URI gets interpretted wrongly, that the function does that as well.

I have Ajax commands that execute a specific get/post command and use the referer to know where they originated eg. `req.headers.referer` which would be something like `http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black`

I have a non standard get in Express, for example:

```
app.get('/data/theme-:theme/:piece', (req, res, next) => {
// server code
}
```

Where the parameters in question are:

```
{
  theme: "chalkboard",
  piece: "black"
}
```

However I have other parts that also have similar incorporated variables within the route. The reason for this is because the route gets dynamically created and updated as the website is used by oneself and others. Because of this, I might need information on one page to be able to query it correctly on another.

From the referer I get a URI string eg.

```
http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black 
or 
http://localhost:3000/hg-1000
```

Then I want to be able to first determine which of the following get commands it matches:

```
app.get('/data/theme-:theme/:piece', (req, res, next) => {});
or 
app.get('/hg-:gameId', (req, res) => {});
```

And lastly get the parameters in a JSON format, eg.

```
{
  "theme": "chalkboard",
  "piece": "black"
}
```

or

```
{
  "gameId": "1000"
}
```

If I have to add custom code to first determine each type of command and then to get the parameters as well it is still fine, as this would be similar to the regex idea that I am currently considering. The problems with this solution is that my regex might not always interpret the URI exactly like Express would and I would have to do this for each of the routes that could get a command. I would prefer a generic solution that acomplishes this if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting what I went with, this is not the way I wanted to do it and I am still hopeful someone might know how to process it as stated in the question. I will update this if I find some corner cases in my solution as it it not been tested fully yet.

I created a class in conjunction with an enum const that can split the URL template into text parts and parameter parts.

I then added a function to the class to check if a URL fits the template. Using that function internally the next thing added to the class was to return an object with the parameters when and if the URL matches.

I then added a method that would loop through an array of all the possible request templates and then determine which one matched and return that one's parameters.

I have attached javascript that uses a couple of url's template types and the output as expected below:

```js
const urlPartsDefinition = {
    TEXT: "text",
    PARAMETER: "parameter"
}
class UrlParts
{
    stringArray = [];
    // uses urlPartsDefinition to define what each tipe in the stringArray is
    itemDefArray = [];
    constructor(urlTemplate){
        let sections = urlTemplate.split("/");
        sections.forEach(uriText => {
            let parameters = uriText.split(":")
            this.stringArray.push(parameters[0]);
            this.itemDefArray.push(urlPartsDefinition.TEXT);
            if (parameters.length === 2)
            {
                this.stringArray.push(parameters[1]);
                this.itemDefArray.push(urlPartsDefinition.PARAMETER);
            } 
        });
    }

    isSameUrl(url) {
        let isSame = true;
        let lastIndexMatched = 0;
        for (let index = 0; index < this.stringArray.length; index++) {
            const textOrParameter = this.stringArray[index];
            const partDefinition = this.itemDefArray[index];
            if (partDefinition === urlPartsDefinition.PARAMETER) continue;
            let urlMatchInd = url.indexOf("/"+textOrParameter,lastIndexMatched);
            if (urlMatchInd === -1) {
                isSame = false;
                break;
            }
            lastIndexMatched = urlMatchInd; // move the position of the last matched so that it will match sequencially while ignoring parameters
        }
        return isSame;    
    }
    getParametersURL(url, checked)
    {
        // don't recheck if iaSameUrl already called
        if (!checked){
        // if not the same, return a blank version of the class expected
            if (!this.isSameUrl(url)) {
                let blankObj = {};
                for (let index = 0; index < this.itemDefArray.length; index++) {
                    const textOrParameter = this.stringArray[index];
                    const partDefinition = this.itemDefArray[index];
                    if (partDefinition === urlPartsDefinition.TEXT) continue;
                    blankObj[textOrParameter]= "";
                }
                return blankObj;
            }
        }
        let urlObj = {};
        let lastIndexMatched = 0;
        for (let index = 0; index < this.stringArray.length; index++) {
            const textOrParameter = this.stringArray[index];
            const partDefinition = this.itemDefArray[index];
            if (partDefinition === urlPartsDefinition.TEXT) {
                let urlMatchInd = url.indexOf("/"+textOrParameter,lastIndexMatched);
                if (urlMatchInd === -1) {
                    isSame = false;
                    break;
                }
                lastIndexMatched = urlMatchInd+textOrParameter.length; // move the position of the last matched so that it will match sequencially while ignoring parameters
            } else {
                let slashMatchInd = url.indexOf("/", lastIndexMatched+1); // end of url parameter
                if (slashMatchInd === -1){ //remaining part of url is the match
                    urlObj[textOrParameter] = url.slice(lastIndexMatched+1);
                    break; // should be the end, if not, well end it anyway (for safety)
                } else {
                    urlObj[textOrParameter] = url.slice(lastIndexMatched+1,slashMatchInd);
                }
                lastIndexMatched = slashMatchInd;
            }
        }
        return urlObj;
    }
}

var allGetCommands = ['/data/games/board','/data/theme-:theme/:piece','/hg-:gameId','/'];
var allGetParts = [new UrlParts(allGetCommands[0]),new UrlParts(allGetCommands[1]),new UrlParts(allGetCommands[2])];

function getUrlAndParameters(urlString){
    for (let index = 0; index < allGetParts.length; index++) {
        const urlPart = allGetParts[index];
        if (urlPart.isSameUrl(urlString))
        {
            return urlPart.getParametersURL(urlString,true);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

let newURLParts = new UrlParts(allGetCommands[1]);
console.log('List of templates:');
console.log(allGetCommands);
console.log()
console.log("============================================================")
console.log('Check to see if "%s" is the same type as following:',allGetCommands[1]);
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black")
console.log(newURLParts.isSameUrl('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red")
console.log(newURLParts.isSameUrl('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/")
console.log(newURLParts.isSameUrl('http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/'))

console.log()
console.log("============================================================")
console.log('Check to see if "%s" parameters can be read from the following:',allGetCommands[1]);
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black")
console.log(newURLParts.getParametersURL('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red")
console.log(newURLParts.getParametersURL('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/")
console.log(newURLParts.getParametersURL('http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/'))

console.log()
console.log("============================================================")
console.log('Check to see if the url can be determined and parameters can be read from the following:');
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black")
console.log(getUrlAndParameters('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-chalkboard/black'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red")
console.log(getUrlAndParameters('http://localhost:3000/data/theme-default/red'))
console.log("http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/")
console.log(getUrlAndParameters('http://localhost:3000/hg-secret-game/'))
```